# InputStream.read(byte[] b) returns unexpected bytes

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm using `bytesCount = InputStream.read(byteArray)` to read data from a client:

My Server:

```
InputStream IS = Connection.getInputStream();
byte[] InData = new byte[1024];
int bytesCount = IS.read(InData);
```

My Client:

```
ObjectOutputStream OOS = null;
try {
    OOS = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
} catch (Exception e) {}
OutputStreamWriter OSW = new OutputStreamWriter(OOS);
try {           
    OSW.write("ABC");
    OSW.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

As you can see, the client sends a string "ABC", but the byte array that the server receives is `InData = [-84, -19, 0, 5, 119, 3, 65, 66, 67, 0, 0, 0, ...]` and `bytesCount = 9`

What are those first 6 bytes?

Comment: When you write to the ObjectOutputStream the object you write is serialized, so the serialization UUID is written also.

Comment: @DimitrisFousteris that's what I thought initially, too, but he is writing to the underlying stream directly with the OutputStreamWriter...

Comment: thanks guys. stackoverflow is very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the ObjectOutputStreamHeader, see `writeStreamHeader()` here: http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/io/ObjectOutputStream-source.html

If you want to serialize the string as UTF8, just use a regular OutputStreamWriter (not an ObjectOutputStream) with UTF8 encoding and write the string:

```
OutputStreamWriter ows = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
osw.write("ABC");
```

Comment: If this answers your question, you may want to accept the answer, so it doesn't show up in the open list any longer....